# Colon in URI causing IllegalArgumentExeception error even after encoding the colon

Tags: java, ibm-cloud, cloudant

I'm trying to do httpget request on the below URL. Here Colon in my URI causing IllegalArgumentExeception error even after encoding the colon using **URLEncoder.encode(":","UTF-8") ;** 
**Exception Error:** Error:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 121
My URI as below:
https://username.cloudant.com/_design/querydoc/_search/querydefect?q=defectid:"37744"&include_docs=true"

Encoded URI:
https://username.cloudant.com/_design/querydoc/_search/querydefect?q=defectid%3A"37744"&include_docs=true".

Exception was thrown for colon present in Query part in URI:
q=defectid:"37744"

q=defectid%3A"37744"

When i put the URI directly on browser I'm able to see my result.
I dont' know what i'm missing here. Please help me.

Comment: So where is the exception being thrown? What do bluemix and cloudant have to do with it?

Comment: The URI is to fetch the document from cloudant db and i getting the  DB service from bluemix. Exception error: Error:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 121: It is on Colon present in the URI

Comment: But if the exception is being thrown when constructing the URI (which still isn't clear, as you still haven't told us where the exception is being thrown) then it's not really related to those. It would help if you'd include the stack trace. Are you sure the problem isn't due to `username:pass.cloudant.com`? That doesn't look right to me.

Comment: Your URI format is also wrong. It should be `https://username:pass@cloudant.com/...`. Are you using [PasswordAuthentication](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/PasswordAuthentication.html) in your code?

Comment: Brother, Exception is thrown on the Colon present in the URI query part. q=defectid:"37744".

Comment: Sorry SubOptimal, Thats a typo. now removed the pass too as I'm not authenticating. Here im getting the exception on the query part in the URI. q=defectid:"37744"

Comment: I think, after a colon it expect a port number like
https://username:password@cloudnet.com:8080/_desgin
While it founds a string ("377dd")